# Does Xpath standard support null value in attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

for example is the following xpath string valid:

```
/web:input_text[@value=null]
```

which means the element doest not has a value attribute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This XPath returns `web:input_text` which don't have `value` attribute:

```
/web:input_text[not(@value)]
```

XPath `/web:input_text[@value=null]` selects `web:input_text` which have value of `value` attribute = `null` node.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`/web:input_text[not(@value)]`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#boolean) instead.